# Unexpeted results for DateTime::diff

Tags: php

I have two dates. The current date from the system and another date, +/- few days around this date. I want to know the difference between these two dates and tried it in the following way:

```
// today is 02/19/2021 ("19.02.2021")
// 1. try: $dstring = "18.02.2021"; result: 1, expected
// 2. try: $dstring = "19.02.2021"; result: 0, expected
// 3. try: $dstring = "20.02.2021"; result: 0, not expected
// 4. try: $dstring = "21.02.2021"; result: 1, not expected
function daysDiff(string $dstring) {
    $now = new DateTime();
    return $now->diff(new DateTime($dstring))->d;
}
```

When $dstring <= today, the function is working fine. But when $dstring > today, the result is 1 day too less.

Any ideas why it is so?

Comment: Look at the whole `diff` result, and not just the `d` property on its own.

Comment: The difference between `2021-02-19 Whatever:Time:ItIsNow` and `2021-02-20 00:00:00` is less than a full day.

Comment: Easy workaround: `$now = new DateTime('00:00:00');` – create a DateTime object that always has the time set to `00:00:00` of “today”, so that it matches the time component of what you are creating from `$dstring`.

Comment: Side note: `new DateTime('today')` also creates a date set to midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as it should with `'today'`.

```
// today is 02/19/2021 ("19.02.2021")
// 1. try: $dstring = "18.02.2021"; result: 1
// 2. try: $dstring = "19.02.2021"; result: 0
// 3. try: $dstring = "20.02.2021"; result: 1
// 4. try: $dstring = "21.02.2021"; result: 2
function daysDiff(string $dstring) {
    // $now = new DateTime();
    $now = new DateTime('today');
    return $now->diff(new DateTime($dstring))->d;
}
```